# Having a powershell file inside my c# project that i can run in my code

Tags: c#, powershell

So in C# i have a powershell file that I want to run. I am looking for a way that I can have the powershell file inside my visual studio project so that this can be ran anywhere and not only on my local computer. Ive seen the other options for adding the powershell file but I cannot seem to get that to work. Thanks

Comment: [Link that might help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: well specifically i wrote code in powershell that i have saved as a file which isnt a simple one line command. Im trying to run a powershell file that i have inside the project not necessarily on the local computer

Comment: then you haven't read enough of the link :-)

Comment: ... ive looked at the link

Comment: And what did you think of the `AddScript` part then? :-)
If your issue is that the path to the script is with the code then you should look into getting the [Environment.CurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.currentdirectory?view=net-5.0)